# API Call Syntax Using JLTMDbClient

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, movie

I've just started accessing TMDB for an iOS app using https://github.com/JaviLorbada/JLTMDbClient - I searched for a solution using relevant search terms before posting and didn't see any other questions asked about this.

When I use the author's example code it works as it should and fetchedData contains a list of popular movies:

```
[[JLTMDbClient sharedAPIInstance] GET:kJLTMDbMoviePopular withParameters:nil andResponseBlock:^(id response, NSError *error) {
    if(!error){
        fetchedData = response;
        NSLog(@"Popular movies: %@", fetchedData);
    }
}];
```

What I need is to return a list of movies for a specific actor (stored in variable 'name', defined as an NSString).  I read the documentation on Github and also TMDB.com to understand the syntax, but I just can't seem to get it.

I tried (unsuccessfully, no error but nothing posted from NSLog):

```
[[JLTMDbClient sharedAPIInstance] GET:kJLTMDbPerson withParameters:@{@"id":name} andResponseBlock:^(id response, NSError *error) {
    if(!error){
        fetchedData = response;
        NSLog(@"Actors movies: %@", fetchedData);
    }
}];
```

Also I'm unsure which of the following I should be using:

- kJLTMDbPerson
- kJLTMDbSearchPerson

Thanks in advance for any responses.